# LG Washer plays dead. Re-plugging sometimes revives it?

Tags: electrical, washing-machine

I have an LG washer: **WM2650H**.

This morning it was dead: pressing the ON/OFF switch did nothing.

When I unplugged, and plugged it in again, I could switch it on again. I left it off for half an hour, and when I wanted to start a load, again the ON/OFF switch did nothing.

So I tried the re-plugging again: Did not fix it. Machine stayed dead.

Ugh... getting desperate I tried one more unplug, plug, and then it **did** fix it.

So. Here we have a washing machine that likes to play dead. And a **power-cycle sometimes helps**?

This is such weird behavior. Would there be a possible cause that can manifest itself in this strange way?

NOTE: The machine is 9 years old. It never missed a beat in that time.

NOTE: Unfortunately, I have poor access to the machine, as the LG dryer seems attached to its top, so I cannot access the back panel. It is unclear to me how to separate LG dryer and LG washer from each other.

NOTE: I checked the door-sensor, which is fine. I'm pretty sure my machine turns on regardless of the door-state, anyway.

NOTE: It is currently running, half-way in a cycle.

NOTE: In Canada, at 110V.

Comment: Might be a thermal overload switch(fuse) which has to cool completely but something is keeping it warm when plugged in.  Assuming the machine ran fine days ago and was just sitting there, this is unlikely.  The other common cause is the control board computer getting into a 'hung' state, so unplugging clears all  memory.  If  you can always complete the wash cycle and always reset by unplugging and waiting 5 minutes, probably not worth a repair call --- yet.

Comment: It is probably the energy star controller that turns things off to save electricity, is yours one that to use it you have to press a on button to wake it up? The cap in the control board is probably at end of life , in plugging and plugging back in reboots it for a cycle , try leaving it unplugged a bit longer when it doesn’t want to restart. This is a guess but they don’t make them to last anymore that’s for sure.

Comment: Any recent appliance - sometimes when you reboot the computer the problem goes away for a while - and they all have computers.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal as what we call micro controllers today were powerful computers 50 years ago and a few discreet components like a bad cap can cause all kinds of problems, as they can take the power needed to start the micro controller.